# How to fix laravel eloquent and DB returning empty items(models) object

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-pagination

I noticed this problem started when I wanted to generate pagination for listStory() method inside a controller.When I investigated I discovered the #items is empty which was not initially. It is calculating the total correctly.

During my investigation I tried:

```
$allStoryByTeller = Story::all();
dd($allStoryByTeller);
```

and it returns:

```
Collection {#344 ▼
  #items: array:10 [▼
    0 => Story {#345 ▶}
    1 => Story {#346 ▶}
    2 => Story {#347 ▶}
    3 => Story {#348 ▶}
    4 => Story {#349 ▶}
    5 => Story {#350 ▶}
    6 => Story {#351 ▶}
    7 => Story {#352 ▶}
    8 => Story {#353 ▶}
    9 => Story {#354 ▶}
  ]
}
```

which should be what the #items in the below output **contains**:

```
public function listStory()
{
    $allStoryByTeller = Story::with([
        'user'
    ])->paginate($perPageCount = 10);
    dd($allStoryByTeller);
    ...
}
```

and this snippet above returns:

```
LengthAwarePaginator {#316 ▼
  #total: 9
  #lastPage: 1
  #items: Collection {#318 ▼
    #items: []
  }
  #perPage: 10
  #currentPage: 2
  #path: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/v1/stories/list"
  #query: []
  #fragment: null
  #pageName: "page"
  +onEachSide: 3
  #options: array:2 [▶]
}
```

I expected the #items to contain 9 models instead of being [] empty as the total is correctly calculated.

Answer (score 1):

I realize that the #items was not loading due to the fact I was on the second page with the Rest Client I was using. I set the perpage count to be 20 so, being on the second page means all the models has been exhausted on the first page.